# Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have cloned a project that uses an old version of .NET Core, version 6. I'm using Visual Studio 22, but I already installed the old version on Visual Studio 22. The problem is when I tried to connect to the database, I got this error

[image: The error]

I was using SQL Server 19, but I thought maybe the error related to the version, so I installed SQL Server 18.12.1, but still got the same issue. I already made sure that SQL Server allowed remote connections

[image: SQL Server]

The project uses ASP.NET Core Web API.
This is my connection string

[image: Connection String]

Comment: The error is clear... and its not related to the version of VS. Literally it cannot connect to the server. Something is preventing the connection being made.

Comment: When I tried to connect in another project, it's worked and connected successfully, this issue related to this project only, how can I know the reason that prevent the connection?

Comment: Generally it is a sql-server issue , your post is not detailed enough to troubleshoot your error. There is an article published by sql-server-team for you to refer to : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance/ba-p/383277

Answer (score -1):

perhaps connection string is not valid.

reverify things

- server name
- database name
- authentication(if applies)

Comment: I already made sure that all of these are valid; the same connection string worked in another project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).